# DS.FixtureAdapter - How to fix adapter without data error in Ember Data 1.0 beta 2

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using a `DS.FixutreAdapter` with stub data while I don't have access to the back-end. I've started upgrading Ember Data 0.13 to Ember Data 1.0 beta 2, but I keep getting an error:

```
"You made a request for a [user] with id [userid], but the adapter's response did not have any data"
```

A few moments ago it (seemingly randomly) started working when I moved the fixture definition...

```
App.User.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 'muosuser',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}]
```

...from the bottom to the top of my `stub-data.js` file, but that may have just been a fluke.

Any thoughts? The docs/guides haven't been updated yet for Data 1.0 beta 2, and everyone seems to ignore the `FixtureAdapter` when writing up transition guides, etc, so I'm kind of lost in the dark. For all I know, the old way of doing fixtures may no longer even apply!

**Edit:** Per request, here's where I'm trying to load the user:

```
App.MainRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({

  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('planner')
  }

, model: function() {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      user: this.store.find('user', this.controllerFor('login').get('username'))
    })
  }

, actions: {
    logout: function() {
      this.controllerFor('login').set('token', null)
      this.transitionTo('login')
    }
  }

})
```

Also per request, here's the entirety of `stub-data.js`:

```
//
// Setup
//

App.Store.reopen({
  adapter: 'fixture'
})

//
// Users
//

App.User.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 'muosuser'
, firstName: 'John'
, lastName: 'Smith'
}]

//
// Snapshots
//

App.Snapshot.FIXTURES = [{
  id: Ember.generateGuid()
, regions: []
, networks: []
}]

//
// Networks
//

var networks = []
var ridicNet = ["Network ", "Krowten "]
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var newId = Ember.generateGuid()
  networks.push({
    id: newId
  , name: ridicNet[i%2] + (i+1)
  , terminals: []
  })
  App.Snapshot.FIXTURES[0].regions.push(newId)
}
networks.push({
  id: Ember.generateGuid()
, name: "k"
, priority: "p4"
, voiceRecognitionRequired: true
, terminals: []
})
App.Snapshot.FIXTURES[0].regions.push(networks[networks.length - 1].id)
App.Network.FIXTURES = networks

//
// Regions
//

App.Region.FIXTURES = [{
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Alaska"
, minLat: 53
, maxLat: 71
, minLon: -167
, maxLon: -131
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Brazil"
, minLat: -33
, maxLat: 5
, minLon: -74
, maxLon: -35
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Caribbean"
, minLat: 14
, maxLat: 23
, minLon: -85
, maxLon: -58
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Central Africa"
, minLat: -5
, maxLat: 15
, minLon: 5
, maxLon: 40
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Chile"
, minLat: -58
, maxLat: -18
, minLon: -76
, maxLon: -64
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "China"
, minLat: 20
, maxLat: 53
, minLon: 74
, maxLon: 134.5
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Columbia"
, minLat: -5
, maxLat: 13
, minLon: -80
, maxLon: -67
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "East Africa"
, minLat: 15
, maxLat: 33
, minLon: 15
, maxLon: 38
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Hawaii"
, minLat: 18
, maxLat: 29
, minLon: -180
, maxLon: -154
}, {
  // id: Ember.generateGuid()
  name: "Australia"
, minLat: -40
, maxLat: -11
, minLon: 113
, maxLon: 154
}]
App.Region.FIXTURES.map(function(fixture) {
  fixture.id = Ember.generateGuid()
  App.Snapshot.FIXTURES[0].regions.push(fixture.id)
})

//
// Terminals
//

var terminals = []
  // , terminalResults = []
for(var i = 0; i < networks.length * 2; i++) {
  var network = networks[Math.floor(i / 2)]
    , region = App.Region.FIXTURES[Math.floor(Math.random() * App.Region.FIXTURES.length)]
    , terminalId = Ember.generateGuid()
    // , latLngId = Ember.generateGuid()

  terminals.push({
    id: terminalId
  , name: 'Terminal ' + (i+1)
  , network: networks[Math.floor(i / 2)].id
  , location: region.id
  // , latLng: latLngId
  })
  if (!network.terminals)
    network.terminals = []
  network.terminals.push(terminals[i].id)
  if (!region.terminals)
    region.terminals = []
  region.terminals.push(terminals[i].id)

  // var minLat = Math.min(region.minLat, region.maxLat)
  //   , maxLat = Math.max(region.minLat, region.maxLat)
  //   , minLon = Math.min(region.minLon, region.maxLon)
  //   , maxLon = Math.max(region.minLon, region.maxLon)
  //   , lat = Math.random() * (maxLat - minLat) + minLat
  //   , lng = Math.random() * (maxLon - minLon) + minLon
  // terminalResults.push({
  //   id: latLngId
  // , terminal: terminalId
  // , lat: lat
  // , lng: lng
  // })
}
App.Terminal.FIXTURES = terminals
// App.TerminalResults.FIXTURES = terminalResults

App.Stub = App.Stub || {}

// Computation
App.Stub.computeAll = function() {
  this._complete = false
  this.computeTerminals()
  this.computeSatellites()
  this._complete = true
}

App.Stub.computeTerminals = function() {
  // Retain IDs
  var terminalResultIds = App.TerminalResults.FIXTURES && App.TerminalResults.FIXTURES.mapProperty('id') || []

  // Clear previously existing data
  App.TerminalResults.FIXTURES = []
  App.Terminal.FIXTURES.map(function(terminal) {
    delete terminal.results
  })

  // Generate new data
  App.Terminal.FIXTURES.forEach(function(terminal, index) {
    if ( !terminal.location ) { return }
    var regions = App.Region.FIXTURES
      , region = regions.findProperty('id', terminal.location)
      , minLat = Math.min(region.minLat, region.maxLat)
      , maxLat = Math.max(region.minLat, region.maxLat)
      , minLon = Math.min(region.minLon, region.maxLon)
      , maxLon = Math.max(region.minLon, region.maxLon)
      , lat = Math.random() * (maxLat - minLat) + minLat
      , lng = Math.random() * (maxLon - minLon) + minLon
    //   , demand = Math.ceiling(Math.random() * 96)

    // switch(demand) {
    //   case 12:
    //   case 48:
    //   case 96:
    //   case 32:
    //   case 64:
    //   case 16:
    //     demand *= 100
    //     break
    //   default:
    //     demand = 0
    // }

    terminal.results = terminalResultIds[index] || Ember.generateGuid()
    App.TerminalResults.FIXTURES.push({
      id: terminal.results
    , terminal: terminal.id
    // , lat: lat
    // , lng: lng
    // , demand: demand
    , location: [lat, lng]
    })
  })
}

App.Stub.computeSatellites = function() {
  // Retain IDs
  var positionIds = App.SatellitePosition.FIXTURES && App.SatellitePosition.FIXTURES.mapProperty('id') || []
    , satelliteIds = App.Satellite.FIXTURES && App.Satellite.FIXTURES.mapProperty('id') || []
    , beamIds = App.SatelliteBeam.FIXTURES && App.SatelliteBeam.FIXTURES.mapProperty('id') || []
    , carrierIds = App.SatelliteCarrier.FIXTURES && App.SatelliteCarrier.FIXTURES.mapProperty('id') || []

  // Clear previously existing data
  App.SatellitePosition.FIXTURES = []
  App.Satellite.FIXTURES = []
  App.SatelliteBeam.FIXTURES = []
  App.SatelliteCarrier.FIXTURES = []

  var satellitePositionOptions = [[[0, -135], [0, -45], [0, 45], [0, 135]]]
  function generateContour(cLat, cLng, radius) {
    var ret = []
    for(var k = 0; k < 60; ++k) {
      var lat = cLat + radius * Math.sin(k * Math.PI / 30)
        , lng = cLng + radius * Math.cos(k * Math.PI / 30)
      ret.push([lat, lng])
    }
    return ret
  }

  // Generate new data
  // SatellitePositions
  for(var spk = 0; spk < 1; ++spk) {
    var positionId = positionIds[spk] || Ember.generateGuid()
    App.SatellitePosition.FIXTURES.push({
      id: positionId
    , satellites: []
    })
    // Satellites
    var totalSatellites = 4
    for(var sk = 0; sk < totalSatellites; ++sk) {
      var satelliteIndex = spk * totalSatellites + sk
        , satelliteId = satelliteIds[satelliteIndex] || Ember.generateGuid()
      App.SatellitePosition.FIXTURES[spk].satellites.push(satelliteId)
      App.Satellite.FIXTURES.push({
        id: satelliteId
      , location: [satellitePositionOptions[spk][sk][0], satellitePositionOptions[spk][sk][1]]
      , beams: []
      })
      // Beams
      var totalBeams = 6
        , distroRadius = Math.random() * 20 + 10  // minimum: 10, maximum: 30
      for(var sbk = 0; sbk < totalBeams; ++sbk) {
        var beamIndex = satelliteIndex * totalBeams + sbk
          , beamId = beamIds[beamIndex] || Ember.generateGuid()
          , contourRadius = Math.random() * (distroRadius / 2) + (distroRadius / 10)
          , contourCenter = {
              lat: App.Satellite.FIXTURES[satelliteIndex].location[0]
                  + distroRadius * Math.sin(sbk * 2 * Math.PI / totalBeams)
            , lng: App.Satellite.FIXTURES[satelliteIndex].location[1]
                  + distroRadius * Math.cos(sbk * 2 * Math.PI / totalBeams)
            }
        App.Satellite.FIXTURES[satelliteIndex].beams.push(beamId)
        App.SatelliteBeam.FIXTURES.push({
          id: beamId
        , contour: generateContour(contourCenter.lat, contourCenter.lng, contourRadius)
        , carriers: []
        })
        // Carriers
        var totalCarriers = 4
        for(var sck = 0; sck < totalCarriers; ++sck) {
          var carrierIndex = beamIndex * totalCarriers + sck
            , carrierId = carrierIds[carrierIndex] || Ember.generateGuid()
          App.SatelliteBeam.FIXTURES[beamIndex].carriers.push(carrierId)
          App.SatelliteCarrier.FIXTURES.push({
            id: carrierId
          , txPower: Math.random()
          , loadFactor: Math.random()
          , ovsf: Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//Reloading
function wait(ms) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred()
  setTimeout(deferred.resolve, ms)
  return deferred.promise()
}

App.Stub.reloadAll = function() {

  this.reloadTerminals()
  this.reloadSatellites()
}

App.Stub._recordReload = function(record) {
  record.reload()
}

App.Stub.reloadTerminals = function() {
  App.Terminal.find().forEach(this._recordReload)
  App.TerminalResults.find().forEach(this._recordReload)
}

App.Stub.reloadSatellites = function() {
  App.SatellitePosition.find().forEach(this._recordReload)
  App.Satellite.find().forEach(this._recordReload)
  App.SatelliteCarrier.find().forEach(this._recordReload)
  App.SatelliteBeam.find().forEach(this._recordReload)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had overridden (and forgotten about) `find` on my adapter to hook it up with a 3rd party loading indicator. I called `_super`, but never returned anything. I don't know why it worked before, but I can definitely see why it wouldn't work now. Stupid mistakes are always the hardest to find!

Comment: Nice!  Glad you got it nailed down.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's some sort of error in your stud-data.js file that was preventing the `User` fixture from being set up correctly.  Fixtures definitely still work.

Comment: Hm... I've separated that bit out, so that the only thing in the new file is literally what I've posted above (`App.User.FIXTURES = ...`). I get no errors from that file, but I'm still seeing the same errors regarding a lack of data. At the very least, it's good to know `FixtureAdapter` is still supposed to work this way.

Comment: The `model` hook in your router is a little strange.  Why are you creating a new Ember object that wraps the user that you look up (which is itself an Ember object)?  Also, are you sure that `this.controllerFor('login').get('username')` is returning the string `'doctor'`?  If it's returning anything else, that means that Ember is trying to look up a user for an ID that does not exist in your fixture data.

Comment: I re-wrote that model function just now to be sure. It's actually returning the string `'muosuser'`, which is what I expect. `'doctor'` was just an example I used here. I wrapped the user in an object in order to allow for other models to be added later (for instance, I was wrapping `App.Region`, `App.Network`, and `App.Terminal` together in a similar fashion on a different route. This wasn't an issue before, but I'm not sure if it's okay now... I haven't made it through to that route to test it yet.

Comment: Hmm.... Hard to say without a running example to look at.  If you can put together a jsbin or jsfiddle I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I've just been having a rough time relearning Ember Data 1.0. Finally got this jsbin working: http://jsbin.com/ajibi/2/edit The `Ember.Object` wrapper seems to work still.